# Is there any way to let android 5.0 not killing my daemon process?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, google-cloud-messaging, push, daemon

I am writing our custom push service (GCM is blocked) on android platform.Because on some phones,the app (even the Service) will be killed when the screen is locked a few minutes.I write a daemon servcie in c which will fork a new process and let it running in a loop to let the push service running.

It worked in android 4.0,but It seems does not work on android 5.0.

I know some push servcice could be running forever when the screen is locked on all android platforms.

I wonder to know how they achieve it?

Comment: yes,GCM and google is blocked in some countries.

Comment: Unfortunate. In such a case you will probably be better off using an existing service like parse rather than inventing the wheel https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: yes,i wonder to know how "parse" keep running in the background.There are also some choices like "parse".In the situtation,we have to invent the wheel because it's not the techincal decision.